# Django 3 - NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, html, django

I'm somehow new to Django, and I don't know how to resolve what seems to be a simple bug. A lot of peoples asked more or less the same question here but any to their fixes worked for me.

So I have 2 apps, one that will work as the main menu for other apps:

Main Menu urls.py :

```
re_path(r'^elec/boq/', include('a0101_boq_elec_main.urls', namespace="SAMM")),
```

Then in the urls.py of that app I have this:

```
app_name='BoqElecMM'
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.boq_index.as_view(), name='boqIndex'),
        path('search/', views.SearchResultView.as_view(), name='searchResult'),
        path('<int:boq_project_id>', views.BoqProjectInfo.as_view(), name='BPInfo'),
]
```

But when I'm trying to use this in my template: `<a href="{% url 'BoqElecMM:BPInfo' %}">` , I'm getting this Django error :

> NoReverseMatch at /elec/boq/
> Reverse for 'BPInfo' not found. 'BPInfo' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Could some of you tell me please, what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to pass a value for the `boq_project_id` parameter, so for example `{% url 'BoqElecMM:BPInfo' boq_project_id=42 %}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a value for the `boq_project_id` parameter, so for example

```
{% url 'BoqElecMM:BPInfo' boq_project_id=42 %}
```

Of course the value you pass to the `boq_project_id` is normally the id of the `project` object. So for example, if in your template you have a `project` object, you can write:

```
{% url 'BoqElecMM:BPInfo' boq_project_id=project.pk %}
```

if you have an `namespace=…` as well, then this should also be prefixed, so with the data in your view, it is:

```
{% url 'SAMM:BoqElecMM:BPInfo' boq_project_id=project.pk %}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay.

I was always thinking that Django will get that key int directly from the URL(?)

Sadly even when I changed the link to this form : 
    
 <td><a href="{% url 'BoqElecMM:BPInfo' boq_project_id=1 %}">{{ project.p_pid }}</a></td>
    
I'm still getting the same error that Django can't reverse my URL name:

"Reverse for 'BPInfo' not found. 'BPInfo' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: @Dudi4PoLFr: ah but you used a `namespace`? What if you use `{% url 'SAMM:BPInfo' boq_project_id=1 %}` instead?

Comment: I tried to switch the namespace to SMAA and even just call the view name without it, in both cases Django is telling me this: "Reverse for 'BPInfo' not found. 'BPInfo' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: @Dudi4PoLFr: `SAMM` or `SMAA`? It looks like you did not include a namespace in the `{% url ... %}`, since it says reverse for **`'BPInfo'`** not found.

Comment: @willem-van-onsemSo just to be sure I have changed my "main menu" url to:
`re_path(r'^elec/boq/', include('a0101_boq_elec_main.urls', namespace='BE-MM')),`
and changed app_name in that app to `app_name = 'BE-MM'` yet when I'm trying to use `{% url 'BE-MM:index' %}` I'm getting this message: _BE-MM' is not a registered namespace_

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem OK for some reason that I don't quite understand this  `SA-MM:BE-MM:index ` works?!

Comment: @Dudi4PoLFr: so the `namespace="SA-MM"`? You also have an `app_name = 'BE-MM'`? Then indeed it is `namespace:app_name:view_name`.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem So in my current version I have: when going to empty URL ' ' Django is calling the 1st app, then this app will serve as a main menu to guide to others apps (also this is where I want to add login screen).  So from this "Main Menu" app I'm calling the 2nd Django app that is the first part of the webapp itself. Neither less thank you for your help.